# Correct method to save an Int into core data?

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity with an Int16 attribute.

[image]

I want to save `var userRepsCount = Int()` which is set by the below stepper method:

```
@IBAction func userRepsStepper(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    userExerciseRepsCounter.text = Int(sender.value).description
    self.userRepsCount = Int(sender.value)
}
```

I want to add this to the attribute and am using `userExercise.reps = userRepsCount` to do so, however I get the error

> Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'Int16'

I was under the impression that Int16 could store int's such as this without issue? What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried to force wrap it as Int16(valueHere)?

Comment: swift suggested userExercise.reps = Int16(userRepsCount)  however I havent seen anyone elses code doing this to save an Int and wondered if there was a correct way to store it

Comment: If it is saved as an Int16, you will have to wrap it like XCode is suggesting. Then, whenever you need to pull it, you will need to wrap it with Int(stuff), so that you can use it as normal. Most likely Apple have changed the store value to Int16 from Int, and your tutorials are just before that update. The Swift updates change a lot of stuff.

Comment: ah ok if thats the answer, i found it odd that there was various Int styles when i only ever see Int used in code as 'Int', the wrapping seemed over complex

Comment: Wrapping is long winded, but swift can't automatically convert the values unfortunately! There are tons of types of Int, look...
http://www.codingexplorer.com/integers-and-numeric-literals-in-swift/, You're essentially just telling Swift it will be between the limits of -32,768 and  32,767

Comment: Is there anything else or has that cleared up your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try wrapping it with `Int64(userRepsCount)`, and then when you pull it, wrap it with `Int(value)` before you process it

Comment: This won't work - see @SkipMia2w3's answer below.
Rather store it as an Int32 in the DB.

Comment: @KarolyNyisztor I am aware, as youc an see below, we discussed it. I just forgot to update my answer, it is now updated.

Comment: This won't work either because the attribute in the DB is of type Int16. 
The OP should update the entity type to Int32 to solve the problem.

Comment: Considering Apple has stopped support for 32bit devices in iOS 11, I would favour Int64(). And per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37050506), would you care to further clarify why Int64() wouldn’t work in iOS core data?

Comment: That's not what I said.
The original issue was - quoting:
"I have an entity with an Int16 attribute."
You just can't squeeze in an Int32 or Int64 value in an Int16 without side effects.

Btw, the fact that Apple stopped supporting 32 bit devices has nothing to do with this debate. It's not that you can't or shouldn't use Int16 or Int32 anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot downcast integers from 32 bit to a lower 16 bit without risk of invalid values. You can only go up to preserve the value. (IE from 16 to 32 or 64). If you absolutely needed to, you can cast using `Int16(value)`.

I would instead recommend using in your CoreData `Integer 32` instead of `int16`. Won't make an obvious/noticeable difference in performance/storage for what you may be doing.

Comment: There isnt a straight 'Int' value option in core data? kist int16 int32 and int64 ?

Comment: Use Int64. You have no reason not to.

Comment: I'd say it'd be best to use Int32 or Int64, it's your choosing, the only difference is that Int64 can hold a higher number

Comment: @infernouk you are right my apologies. Fixed in answer. And rob mayoff is right. Integer 64 is a viable option as well.

Comment: to clarify, regardless i have to wrap my Int as a 64 then as per Danny's answer?

Comment: Yes exactly, just wrap it `Int64(value)`

Comment: Wrapping with `Int(value)` gives you a `Int32` type.

Comment: will Int64 not work on older iOS versions? i.e. pre-64 bit iOS versions?